# SQL Uniqueness Across Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, unique-constraint

I have two SQL tables: Users and clients.

Every row in the users table has a set of clients in the clients table, linked by the users table `id` field and the clients table `user_id` field.

The users table has a `username` field which is unique.

The clients table has a `user_id` field AND `clientname` field that together are unique (i.e. `clientnames` can exist more than once, but must have different `user_ids`)

My question is: How do I add a rule that forces uniqueness between the `username` field in the users table and the `clientname` field in the clients table? Is it even possible?

i.e. no `username` can be the same as a `clientname` , and no `clientname` can be the same as a `username`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have a third table which stores both. Something like this:

```
unique_ids
----------
  identifier (UNIQUE)
  used_where (name/id of table that the identifier is used in)

users
-----
  username (FK to unique_ids.identifier)

clients
-------
  clientname (FK to unique_ids.identifier)
```

This way, both tables share one common table that contains the values that need to be unique and uniquness contraints can be easily enforced in that shared table. You will need a simple on-insert trigger (on both tables) as well that will check the `used_where` field to ensure that the identifier is not already used by the other table (because if I understand your requirement, `username` must be unique in `users` but `clientname` does not need to be unique in `clients`).

If you don't want to introduce new structures and modify existing ones, you could try using an on-insert trigger on `clients` and `users` that checks to make sure a new record does not contain an existing username/clientname.

Comment: Surely this doesn't prevent the same username appearing in both the `users` and the `clients` table? The on-insert trigger would have to be used for this.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon: Good point, the first method still needs a trigger, though a slightly simpler one.

Comment: Add a type column to your unique_ids table. Propagate it to both child tables. Include it in FK constraints. Have CHECK constraints verify that type=1 in users table, and type=2 in clients table.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov - yep, that would work.